# Declare Variables from a shell script in the shell

Tags: linux, shell, sh

Can you guys tell me how to write a shell script which declares for example a variable in the shell like this: var="foobar". It just has to write the exact same thing like I would write it manually in the shell.

appreciate help because this would help me a lot ! I am not so experienced in shell scripting :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, you have to create a script (`file.sh`, for example) containing the line:

```
var="foobar"
```

and then source the file:

```
source file.sh
```

or

```
. file.sh
```

Comment: Just want to add that there is _NO_ way to influence the parent shell if it calls a script as a new process (i. e. just by `./script.sh` or similar).  To enable a script to influence its caller one _must_ use `source` (abbreviated as `.`) or do other stuff like `eval` the output of a called script: `eval "$(./script.sh)"`.